# How two superpose two activty with a transparency

Tags: android, android-activity, transparency

I would like to superpose the Activity2 with transparency upper of Activity1.

For exemple, Activity1 is the google maps application launched in an Activity, I would like to display in a other Activity2, some elements or layer upper the Activity1.

In waiting for your answers.
Stan

Comment: There's no guarantee that this will work, as Activity1 can be destroyed at any time. What you'd want is to superimpose another layout over Activity1 from within Activity1. Base Activity1 on a FrameLayout.

Answer (score -1):

put a linear layout over your Activity1 and set the desired alpha in XML.
Then inflate your Activity2 into the linear layout or frame layout, use what you want.